# How can I alllow the selection of multiple files in multiple selections?

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

How can I alllow the selection of multiple files in multiple selections?

For example using this code snippet:

```html
Select files: <input type="file" name="myFile" multiple>
```

1. Click 'Browse'; select a file.
2. Click 'Browse'; select another file.

This results in only the second file being selected. I want both files to be selected. Is this possible using the basic `input` control?

Comment: Hold CTRL to select multiple elements or you can use shift to select range, you can also draw selection if you click and drag on empty area, this is basic of how OS works.

Comment: @jcubic; I specifically want to know if the scenario I outlined can be achieved.

Comment: I think it's not possible with js.

Comment: Sorry didn't read the question carefully, this don't work that way, each time you click on browse, you will get another selection. You need multiple inputs. But with JavaScript and CSS you can make it look like one input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any practical way.

The implementation of the UI for a file input is browser dependant (and most browsers just implement the standard control for the OS). You can't change that.

The closest you could get would probably be to do something along the lines of, in response to a file being selected, duplicating the input and hiding the original. Then a second interaction would change the selection of the newest input while preserving the older ones.

This would break the normal mechanisms provided for users to deselect previously chosen options and be inconsistent with the behaviour of file selection on other sites so I'd *strongly* advise against it.